# Perl : CRTL C ignored when calling subroutine instead of exiting

Tags: perl

So the script is something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Term::ReadLine;

$SIG{'INT'} = 'INT_handler';
sub INT_handler {
  print "[+] Abording\n";
  home();
}

my $term = Term::ReadLine->new('Simple Perl calc');

sub home {

  my $prompt = "\$> ";
  my $OUT = $term->OUT || \*STDOUT;

  while ( defined ($_ = $term->readline($prompt)) ) {
    my $com = $_;
    print $com."\n";
    if ($com eq 'exit') {
        exit;
    }
  option(); # another subroutine when the input is transferred to
  }
}

home();
```

what I get:

```
$>                                                                              
[+] Abording
$> # I pushed CRTL C but nothing shows                                                                             
$> # same here
```

What I want to achieve is to be able to go to `home()` without exiting, and keep the `$SIG{'INT'}` working.

I have tried some other methods ( labels, using if statement ), but it will take too long cause the input is used in long processes

Comment: Why would you call `home` from the signal handler, when your code is already in `home` as you never exit it?

Comment: ah! after the input , I need to call another subroutine , in which some processes take some time , so I want to return to `home()` in that case

Comment: +1, good question, but please capitalize the first letter of each sentence. Also, it is usual in English to use commas as the comment you are reading does, with a space after but not before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not call `home()` in your signal handler.

Just set a flag that you check in your input loop. When `$term->readline()` returns, because it was interrupted by CTRL-C, check that the flag was set, reset it and continue to loop.

Here is your updated code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Term::ReadLine;

$SIG{'INT'} = 'INT_handler';
my $interrupted;
sub INT_handler {
    $interrupted++;
}

my $term = Term::ReadLine->new('Simple Perl calc');

sub home {
    my $prompt = "\$> ";
    my $OUT = $term->OUT || \*STDOUT;

    while ( defined ($_ = $term->readline($prompt)) || $interrupted ) {
        if ($interrupted) {
            $interrupted = 0;
            print "\n[+] Aborting\n";
            next;
        }
        my $com = $_;
        print $com."\n";
        if ($com eq 'exit') {
            exit;
        }
    }
}

home();

exit 0;
```

Test output:

```
$ perl dummy.pl
$> test
test
$> ^C

[+] Aborting
$> ^C

[+] Aborting
$> sdasd^C

[+] Aborting
$> exit
exit
```

**NOTE:** there seems to be one issue still: you need to press return to get the prompt back. Probably something to do with how `Term::Readline` works.

Comment: Yeah it does work , but supposing that i am having double loop , I mean after the input im gonna loop the string , need I to flag it?

Comment: I think as long as you're not calling `$term->readline()` (or do other I/O) before entering the outer loop again, you should be fine.